# On covariance and pseudocovariance of a complex random vector

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, complex-numbers, random-variables

I am currently studying complex FastICA and the [paper](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/IJNS00.pdf) says that

> Suppose $\mathbf{s}$ is a $n\times1$ complex random vector. If $\mathbf{s}$ has zero mean, unit variance, and uncorrelated real and imaginary part of equal variances, then $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]=\mathbf{I}_n$ and $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]=\mathbf{0}_n$.

I don't quite get how $E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]=\mathbf{0}_n$ come about from the conditions.

We have the covariance matrix as
\begin{align}
\operatorname{cov}(\mathbf{s}) 
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]-E[\mathbf{s}]E[\mathbf{s}^H] \\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]-\mathbf{0}_{n\times1}\mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]\\
\end{align}
and the pseudocovariance
\begin{align}
\operatorname{pcov}(\mathbf{s}) 
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]-E[\mathbf{s}]E[\mathbf{s}^T] \\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]-\mathbf{0}_{n\times1}\mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
&= E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]\\
\end{align}
I don't quite get how to equate the last line of covariance matrix to identity and the pseucovariance to zero.

If I were to write out the matrix,
\begin{align}
E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]
&=E\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
s_1s_1^* & s_1s_2^* &\cdots & s_1s_n^*\\
s_2s_1^* & s_2s_2^* &\cdots & s_2s_n^*\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
s_ns_1^* & s_ns_2^* &\cdots & s_ns_n^*\\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]
&=E\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
s_1s_1 & s_1s_2 &\cdots & s_1s_n\\
s_2s_1 & s_2s_2 &\cdots & s_2s_n\\
\vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\
s_ns_1 & s_ns_2 &\cdots & s_ns_n\\
\end{bmatrix}\right\}
\end{align}

I still can't quite figure how all of these eventually becomes identity and zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay now that I ponder for a few more hours.

I know for sure that $E[s_is_j^*]=E[s_i]E[s_j]=0$ and $E[s_is_j]=E[s_i]E[s_j]=0$ where $i\ne j$ so I have

\begin{align}
E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^H]
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[s_is_i^*])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[(a+ib)(a-ib)]) &&(\because s_i:=a+ib)\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[a^2+b^2])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[a^2]+E[b^2])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{Var}[a]+E[a]^2+\operatorname{Var}[b]+E[b]^2)
&& (\because \operatorname{Var}[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2)\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{Var}[s_i]+0)
&& (\because E[a]=E[b]=0,\\
&&& \qquad\operatorname{Var}[s]:=\operatorname{Var}[a]+\operatorname{Var}[b])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(1)
&& (\because \operatorname{Var}[s]:=1)\\
&=\mathbf{I}_n
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
E[\mathbf{s}\mathbf{s}^T]
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[s_is_i])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[s_i^2])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[a^2+2abi-b^2])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[a^2]+2E[abi]-E[b^2])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(E[a^2]-E[b^2])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(\operatorname{Var}[a]-\operatorname{Var}[b])\\
&=\operatorname{diag}(0)\\
&=\mathbf{0}_n
\end{align}

I will just leave my answer here in case someone were to be in my position in the future since I can't find any good reference for this.